# Does creating a tuple of a set in python always result in the same tuple

Tags: python, set, tuples

In my code, i convert a set to a tuple in order to use it as a dictionary key. Since a set does not have an order and a tuple is, it would seem that:

```
tuple(some_set)
```

does not guarantee the same tuple every time, since an order has to be created. However, by testing this in practice it seems that a given set is converted to the same tuple each time, as demonstrated by the following code printing 1.

```
my_tuples = set()

for i in range(100000000):
    my_tuples.add(tuple(set(range(100))))


print(len(my_tuples))
```

I could not find any documentation about this, but does the tuple() function always return the same tuple on a given set? And is this somewhere explicitly stated?

Comment: What is your expected output then? Code is correct, It's returning same tuple because range is same ,  What do you expect from it ?

Comment: The order of entries could change dependent on day, computer architecture, used python version, environment variables, OS, wheather, stellar constellation etc. so it's always best to force a specific order.

Comment: @AyodhyankitPaul tuple has an order and a set doesn't. Therefore, the function tuple({0,1,2}) might return (0,1,2),  but also (0,2,1). My test could just be because of some implementation, but as long as it is not documented somewhere i have no guarantee that this happens for truly all cases (now and in future versions, unless changelogs state different)

Comment: @syntonym Do you have any source for that?

Comment: @mottie91 No, not really. But these undocumented behavoirs can produce really nasty bugs. Imagine you are saving your sets in multiple remote servers and the fastest answer is then taken, but the python version on the servers differ by some minor version. Then in two years you wonder why this specific bug only occurs if it rains in france. In my experience it's just not worth (without a really good reason) to depend on such unspecified behavior.

Comment: @syntonym Agreed, but that is why i asked in my question if this behavior is explicitly stated somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sets are not "randomly" ordered, they are ordered based on an internal logic that may change (e.g. in different Python versions). This internal logic should be ignored during development, and you should consider a set as not having any order.

Indeed,

```
set([-1,-2]) == set([-2,-1]) # is True
```

but

```
tuple(set([-1,-2])) == tuple(set([-2,-1])) # is False
```

If you have a look at what the two tuples are, you'll find that `tuple(set([-1,-2])), tuple(set([-2,-1]))` is `((-1, -2), (-2, -1))`.

So, the insertion order of the elements in a set influences how they are subsequently iterated upon, and since `tuple()` is based on the iterator of the set, the results are the ones you see above.

Finally, if you're not going to change "context" (e.g. python version) and the creation of the sets always occurs under the same circumstances, you can safely assume that the order of the elements will be the same (**beware, though, that this may be acceptable when scripting something that you will throw away tomorrow, but not anywhere else**).

Comment: +1 But it's interesting that in python 3.7.2 at least, both `tuple(set([1,2]))` and `tuple(set([2,1]))` return `(1,2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Integers hash to themselves :

```
example=[5,0,1,2,3,4]
print(set(example))
```

output:

```
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

It's not that hard to come up with examples of sets of integers which won't be in sorted order.

```
example=[-5,0,1,2,3,4]
print(set(example))
```

output:

```
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, -5}
```